# Can't figure how to pass a file path to the GET in spark-java micro service

Tags: spark-java

I have an HTTP GET defined like below in a spark-java microservice, that using POI, will return the Word document's text.

The problem I have (and it's probably simple to fix), is that I can't pass a path to the GET since it misinterprets it.

I've tried escaping the path, putting name=value, quotes, etc., but it doesn't work yet.

If I set the path inside the actual micro-service, then it's all good. Therefore, I'm just confused how to set a path in the GET.

Should be something close to:
**$curl localhost:4567/docxtext/Test.docx**

(but allowing a path for the "Text.docx" part -- for example, "./Test.docx")

Thanks for any suggestions!

- m

  get("/docxtext/:docName", (request, response) ->
          {
              return getWordDocText(request.params("docName"));
          });

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by using query params, like the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:1234/docxtext?docName=yourEscapedPath

get("/docxtext", (request, response)->{
  String docName = request.queryParams("docName");
  return "HI";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that worked. Thanks.
I just needed to substitute %2 for / and it worked fine.
Appreciate your reply.
Thanks again.